# Animating a trajectory of Cannon Shells C-program

Tags: c, physics

I am unable to see what I did wrong with my code. I am supposed to determine the trajectory that two cannon shells will take when fired at 500 m/s at an angle of 50 degrees above the horizontal. One of the shells is assumed to experience no drag and the other experiences a drag coefficient of 0.0001. I was wondering as to why my code wasn't plotting correctly. Any help would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "philsplot.h"


// Number of shells
#define N 2
// Defining the value of PI
#define PI 3.1415926535

  int main()
  {
    double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, theta = (50 * (PI/180));
    int color, style;
    double expand;

    // philsplot function to open an x-window
    open_plot("800x600");
    int i,j;
    double vx[N], vy[N], x[N], y[N], h, ax[N], ay[N];
    h = 0.01;

    // philsplot function erases the canvas after flushpoint is called
    erase_plot();

    // plot using km for distance
    xmin = 0; xmax = 1;
    ymin = 0; ymax = 1;
    expand = 1.1;
    color = 1;

    // philsplot function to set limits of the plotting canvas
    box_plot(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,expand,color,"Distance (km)","Height (km)","RRRR","TTTT");
    // philsplot function that maps the plotting canvas onto the screen
    flush_plot();

    style = 2;
    color = 3;
    expand = 1.0;
    // The initial values
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
      // want the initial x-position to be this
      x[i] = 0;
      // want the initial y-position to be this
      y[i] = 0;
      // want the initial x-velocity to be this
      vx[i] = 0.5*cos(theta);
      // want the initial y-velocity to be this
      vy[i] = 0.5*sin(theta);
    }
      for(j=0; j<N-1; j++) {
    // Using Euler's method you get this:
    ax[j] = (-0.0001) * (0.5) * vx[j];
    ay[j] = (-0.00981) - (0.0001) * (0.5) * vy[j];
    vx[j] = vx[j] - ax[j] * h;
    vy[j] = vy[j] - ay[j] * h;
    x[j] = x[j] + vx[j] * h;
    y[j] = y[j] + vy[j] * h;

      putpoint_plot(x[j],y[j],10, style, color, expand, 1);

      flush_plot();

      delay_plot(1000);

    }

    printf("hit enter for next plot: ");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, one thing that doesn't make sense is `vx[j] = vx[j] - ax[j] * h;` and the same for `y`. Why are you subtracting acceleration rather than adding?  Additionally, you are only computing one point. Why do expect to get a full arc simulation?

Comment: Please distill this into a [mcve], rather than dumping your whole project on us with a "this doesn't work".

Comment: You did not differentiate the drag coefficient between the two instances, you could use a array for these coefficients. Also check again how to compute drag in a two-dimensional motion and what the formula for air drag is.

Comment: I see that I am only computing one point, that's the problem I'm having, why am I only computing one point? I've got three other separate variations of the similar equation using different coding methods, however I thought this one would be the most Minimal and Complete example. If you would like to take a look at the other three separate programs, I'd be happy to copy them onto this for your reference. However the only problem I am having is the equation representing one point, rather than simulating a trajectory arc.

Comment: In response to LutzL, do you mean create an array that has the coefficient of drag being 0 and 0.0001? Then using that array as the source to refer to in the code?

Comment: "why am I only computing one point?" - because your loop only iterates for the shell's number. You need to loop (and integrate) over time. Moreover, note that your (2nd) loop only iterates the 1st shell, and not the 2nd!

Comment: If you start with code for a single shell at a time, it'd be much easier for you to follow the program's flow.

Comment: One more comment about the physics model - the Drag force is a quadratic function of the velocity. D = 0.5 * rho * S * Cd * V^2 = K * V^2. Thus, you should calculate the magnitude of the Drag (from the magnitude of the speed), then separate that to its X and Y components.

Comment: Figured out my problem, I forgot to include a while loop so the program can run over a set time.